# How can I customize the position of a QuickAction?

Tags: java, android, quickaction

I have a clickable FrameLayout and I want to display a few quick actions on top of it after a long press. I can create a QuickAction to pop out of it like the old Twitter app, but I'm not sure how to display it like the current one.

[image: Old Twitter]    [image: Newer Twitter]

Comment: [How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: Seems to be the same as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398184/twitter-for-android-like-swipe-to-side-quick-menu) which I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398184/twitter-for-android-like-swipe-to-side-quick-menu/7462204#7462204)

Comment: @Knickedi I saw your post and I took a look at your toolkit before I posted this, but I'm not sure how to use it without a ListView.

Comment: Ah ok, well your right, it's tied to a listview. But since your showing a picture of a list here i assumed that's what you want ;-)

Comment: Actually, that's a great idea, I could provide a view group which will allow you to use that kind of stuff without a listview. That's briliant, thanks :-D I'll share my results when i make progress!

Comment: @Knickedi Yeah, that sounds perfect. Definitely let me know how things go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while but like I promised in the comment section:
Here's the Twitter like feature you were asking for which works without a list view.

You will find all information in my answer to [Twitter for Android like swipe-to-side quick menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398184/twitter-for-android-like-swipe-to-side-quick-menu/7462204#7462204)

Comment: Very nice. I had forgotten about this, actually.