# How to do slide effect as per contacts app on Galaxy devices?

Tags: android, slide, android-contacts, galaxy

Seems odd that I couldn't find any info for this:

There is a nice feature on Samsung Galaxy devices within the contacts app, which allows the user to slide a contact list item for quick calling and sending a quick SMS message, as shown [**here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=7HgDlQLc258#t=93s).

My questions are:

1. Is there an easy way to do it? maybe a third party library?
2. If not, how would you implement such a thing?
3. Is it even allowed to add this feature to my app (patents problems)?

Comment: Perhaps, you could create a custom adapter. Within the getView() method of this adapter you could call setOnTouchListener method on the view. Then with some logic you should be able to accomplish something similar

Comment: yes , but the question is what to do per view . of course it should be in an adapter since it's in a listView ... :)

Comment: [Check out this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398184/twitter-for-android-like-swipe-to-side-quick-menu) The accepted answer has a link to a library that will help you accomplish what you need.

Comment: that's very cool , but i think the one on the galaxy devices looks a little different , with a gradient that takes over the more you move the finger .

Comment: ok , i've tested this sample code (after converting it to use the new sdk) , and sadly it doesn't work well - it doesn't respond well to touch events and it isn't as smooth as on the contacts app .